# SQL Server through JDBC in PySpark

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, pyspark

```
os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "--master yarn-client --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=6144 \
        --executor-memory 1G –jars  /mssql/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar --driver-class-path  /mssql/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar")

source_df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(
          url='dbc:sqlserver://xxxx.xxxxx.com',
          database = "mydbname",
          dbtable=mytable,
          user=username,
          password=pwd,
          driver='com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver'
          ).load()
```

I am trying to load SQL Server Table using Spark Context.

But running into the following error.

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o59.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I have the jar file in the location. Is that the correct jar file?
Is there a problem with the code.

Not sure what is the problem.

Scala error

```
scala> classOf[com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
<console>:27: error: object sqlserver is not a member of package com.microsoft
              classOf[com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]


scala> classOf[com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
<console>:27: error: object jdbc is not a member of package com.microsoft
              classOf[com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver]
```

Answer (score 14):

The configuration is similar to Spark-Oracle configuration.
Here is my Spark-sqlserver configurations:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master('local[*]')\
    .appName('Connection-Test')\
    .config('spark.driver.extraClassPath', '/your/jar/folder/sqljdbc42.jar')\
    .config('spark.executor.extraClassPath', '/your/jar/folder/sqljdbc42.jar')\
    .getOrCreate()


sqlsUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://your.sql.server.ip:1433;database=YourSQLDB'

qryStr = """ (
    SELECT *
    FROM yourtable
    ) t """

spark.read.format('jdbc')\
    .option('url',sqlsUrl)\
    .option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')\
    .option('dbtable', qryStr )\
    .option("user", "yourID") \
    .option("password", "yourPasswd") \
    .load().show()
```

1. Set the location of the jar file you downloaded => "**/your/jar/folder/sqljdbc42.jar**". The jar file can be downloaded from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54671 (*google sqljdbc42.jar if the link does not work)
2. Set the correct jdbc url => **'jdbc:sqlserver://your.sql.server.ip:1433;database=YourSQLDB'** (change the port number if you have a different setting)
3. Set the correct driver name => **.option('driver', 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')**
4. Enjoy

Answer (score 7):

I installed Spark in Windows and got the same error while connecting to SQL Server following the steps described here https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/sql-databases.html#python-example. I solved this like below -

1) Download SQL Server JDBC driver from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774.

2) Unzip as "Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server"

3) Find the JDBC jar file (like sqljdbc42.jar) in folder  "Microsoft JDBC Driver 6.0 for SQL Server".

4) Copy the jar file (like sqljdbc42.jar) to "jars" folder under Spark home folder. In my case, I copied it and pasted it to "D:\spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6\jars"

5) restart pyspark

In this way I solved this for Windows server.